# svg/js обратный отсчет

Tags: javascript, svg

Как изменить js код так, чтобы по истечении 59 секунд счетчик не замирал на 0 секунде, а начинал заново?

```js
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.svgTimer = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.svgTimer.defaults, options);

        var template = "<div class='svg-hexagonal-counter'>"
            + "<div class='hint'><span class='hint-count'></span><br><span class='hint-text'></span></div>"
            + "<svg class='counter' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 776 628'>"
            + "<path class='track' d='M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z'></path>"
            + "<path class='fill' d='M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z'></path>"
            + "</svg>"
            + "</div>";

        return this.each(function() {
            // Build dom for svg countdown
            var parentEl = $(this);
            parentEl.append(template);

            //define dom elements
            var track = parentEl.find('.track');
            var fill = parentEl.find('.fill');
            var hintCount = parentEl.find('.hint-count');
            var hintText = parentEl.find('.hint-text').text(opts.hint);


            //set time and offset
            var time = opts.time; /* how long the timer runs for */
            var initialOffset = 2160;
            var i = 1;

            if(opts.direction === 'forward'){
                hintCount.text(i);
            } else if (opts.direction === 'backwards') {
                var count = opts.time - i;
                hintCount.text(count);
            } else {
                hintCount.text(i);
            }

            //draw initial hexagon
            track.css('stroke', opts.track);
            

            //run timer
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                //track.css('stroke', opts.track);
                fill.css({
                    'stroke': opts.fill,
                    'stroke-dashoffset': initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/time)) + 'px',
                    'transition': 'stroke-dashoffset 1s ' +  opts.transition
                });
                if(opts.direction === 'forward'){
                    hintCount.text(i);
                } else if (opts.direction === 'backwards') {
                    var count = opts.time - i;
                    hintCount.text(count);
                } else {
                    hintCount.text(i);
                }

                if (i == time) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
                i++;
            }, opts.interval);
        });
    };

    $.fn.svgTimer.defaults = {
        time: 60,
        interval: 1000,
        direction: 'forward',
        track: 'rgb(56, 71, 83)',
        fill: 'rgb(104, 214, 198)',
        transition: 'linear',
        hint: 'seconds'

    }
}( jQuery ));

//initialize plugin 
$(function () {
    $('.timer-days').svgTimer({
        direction: 'backwards',
        time: 35,
        interval: 86400000,
        hint: 'days'
    });

    $('.timer-hours').svgTimer({
        direction: 'backwards',
        time: 18,
        interval: 3600000,
        hint: 'hours'
    });

    $('.timer-minutes').svgTimer({
        direction: 'backwards',
        time: 54,
        interval: 60000,
        hint: 'minutes'
    });

    $('.timer-seconds').svgTimer({
        direction: 'backwards',
        time: 60,
        interval: 1000,
        hint: 'seconds'
    });
});
```

```css
.svg-hexagonal-counter {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.svg-hexagonal-counter .hint {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    /*line-height: 200px;*/
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/*svg {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}*/


.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter{
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter .track,
.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter .fill {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    stroke-width: 30;
    transform: translate(290px, 800px)rotate(-120deg);
}

.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter .fill {
    stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 2160;
    stroke-dashoffset: 2160;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer-days"></div>
<div class="timer-hours"></div>
<div class="timer-minutes"></div>
<div class="timer-seconds"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как изменить js код так, чтобы по истечении 59 секунд счетчик не
>   замирал на 0 секунде, а начинал заново?

За отсчет отвечает таймер, установленный с помощью `setInterval` который под достижению нужного числа срабатываний (`time == i`) очищается, используя `clearTimeout`. Отсюда следует, что для решения задачи, необходимо сделать две вещи:

1. сбросить `i` в начальное значение
2. не останавливать таймер

Для удобства, можно внести свойство `repeat`  в настройки таймера.

То есть в вашем коде будут следующий изменения:

```
if (i == time) {
    if(opts.repeat){
        i = -1;
    } 
    else clearInterval(interval);
}
```

и

```
$.fn.svgTimer.defaults = {
     ....
     repeat: false,
}

....

    $('.timer-seconds').svgTimer({
        ....
        repeat: true,           
    });
```

Это отвечает на вопрос, как сделать чтобы таймер перезапускался. Однако есть один арфетфакт, при достижении конечного значения транзишен анимации будет срабатывать обратно к нулю. Его также следует модифцировать, если надо.

```js
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.svgTimer = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.svgTimer.defaults, options);

        var template = "<div class='svg-hexagonal-counter'>"
            + "<div class='hint'><span class='hint-count'></span><br><span class='hint-text'></span></div>"
            + "<svg class='counter' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 776 628'>"
            + "<path class='track' d='M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z'></path>"
            + "<path class='fill' d='M723 314L543 625.77 183 625.77 3 314 183 2.23 543 2.23 723 314z'></path>"
            + "</svg>"
            + "</div>";

        return this.each(function() {
            // Build dom for svg countdown
            var parentEl = $(this);
            parentEl.append(template);

            //define dom elements
            var track = parentEl.find('.track');
            var fill = parentEl.find('.fill');
            var hintCount = parentEl.find('.hint-count');
            var hintText = parentEl.find('.hint-text').text(opts.hint);


            //set time and offset
            var time = opts.time; /* how long the timer runs for */
            var initialOffset = 2160;
            var i = 1;

            if(opts.direction === 'forward'){
                hintCount.text(i);
            } else if (opts.direction === 'backwards') {
                var count = opts.time - i;
                hintCount.text(count);
            } else {
                hintCount.text(i);
            }

            //draw initial hexagon
            track.css('stroke', opts.track);
            

            //run timer
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                //track.css('stroke', opts.track);
                fill.css({
                    'stroke': opts.fill,
                    'stroke-dashoffset': initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/time)) + 'px',
                    'transition': 'stroke-dashoffset 1s ' +  opts.transition
                });
                if(opts.direction === 'forward'){
                    hintCount.text(i);
                } else if (opts.direction === 'backwards') {
                    var count = opts.time - i;
                    hintCount.text(count);
                } else {
                    hintCount.text(i);
                }

                if (i == time) {
                    if(opts.repeat){
                      i = -1;
                    } 
                    else clearInterval(interval);
                }
                i++;
            }, opts.interval);
        });
    };

    $.fn.svgTimer.defaults = {
        time: 60,
        interval: 1000,
        direction: 'forward',
        track: 'rgb(56, 71, 83)',
        fill: 'rgb(104, 214, 198)',
        transition: 'linear',
        hint: 'seconds',
        repeat: false,

    }
}( jQuery ));

//initialize plugin 
$(function () {


    $('.timer-seconds').svgTimer({
        direction: 'backwards',
        time: 10,
        interval: 1000,
        hint: 'seconds',
        repeat: true,
       
    });
});
```

```css
.svg-hexagonal-counter {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.svg-hexagonal-counter .hint {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    /*line-height: 200px;*/
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/*svg {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}*/


.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter{
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter .track,
.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter .fill {
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    stroke-width: 30;
    transform: translate(290px, 800px)rotate(-120deg);
}

.svg-hexagonal-counter .counter .fill {
    stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 2160;
    stroke-dashoffset: 2160;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="timer-seconds"></div>
```